# TweepError Failed to parse JSON payload - random error

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy package in Python to collect tweets. I track several users and collect their latest tweets. For some users I get an error like "Failed to parse JSON payload: ", e.g. "Failed to parse JSON payload: Expecting ',' delimiter or '}': line 1 column 694303 (char 694302)". I took a note of the userid and tried to reproduce the error and debug the code. The second time I ran the code for that particular user, I got results (i.e. tweets) with no problem. I adjusted my code so that when I get this error I try once more to extract the tweets. So, I might get this error once, or twice for a user, but in a second or third attempt the code returns the tweets as usual without the error. I get similar behaviour for other userids too.

My question is, why does this error appear randomly? Nothing else has changed. I searched on the internet but couldn't find a similar report. A snippet of my code follows

```
#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []
ntries = 0
#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
while True:
    try: #if process fails due to connection problems, retry.
        if beforeid:
            new_tweets = api.user_timeline(user_id = user,count=200, since_id=sinceid, max_id=beforeid)
        else:
            new_tweets = api.user_timeline(user_id = user,count=200, since_id=sinceid)
        break
    except tweepy.error.RateLimitError:
        print "Rate limit error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        print("Timeout, retry in 5 minutes...\n")
        time.sleep(60 * 5)
        continue
    except tweepy.error.TweepError as er:
        print('TweepError: ' + er.message)
        if er.message == 'Not authorized.':
            new_tweets = []
            break
        else:
            print(str(ntries))
            ntries +=1
            pass
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        new_tweets = []
        break
```